# Scroll a theoretically infinite log file

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Python) How do I scroll a live log file that is constantly being updated and search for a specific string?

```
def scroll_logs(logfile):
    logfile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        line = logfile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line
```

I don't think this works or at least I'm not using it correctly.